# TortoiseSVN icon overlays don't show up

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can see just normal, modified and added icon overlays using TortoiseSVN. I can't see locked, conflicted, readonly and others icon. I set tortoise overlay icons at the highest priority in the registry. It doesn't work. Can you help me? I have Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turn out that I had to delete other overlay icons from the registry. The highest priority isn't enough. Overlay icons was reduced to 11 elements and it started works.